# How to set custom filename for pabot result (html)

Tags: automated-tests, appium, robotframework

I implemented test cases for my application and decided to run it everyday. The problem is the result of the previous test will be overwritten by the latest test result. I need to keep them both so I came up with a solution that include the test date and time in the report name, for example; *report-202111181704.html* (use time in 24-hour format).

I searched through the internet and did not found any solution yet. Anybody here know the solution? or any alternative solution will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of setting .html file name, I create a folder and put the result there.

To do this, add `--outputdir` in pabot command so it's gonna look like this

`pabot --pabotlibport $PABOT_PORT --pabotlib --resourcefile ./DeviceSet.dat --processes $thread --verbose --outputdir ./result/$OUTPUT_DIR $ENV`

where
`$OUTPUT_DIR`=`date + "%Y%m%d-%H%M"`

The output folder gonna be like `./result/20220301-2052`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you execute your tests. From command line you can save the date to variable. Then use this variable to change the name of generated outputs. For example

```
date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
robot --output ${date}output.xml --log ${date}log.html --report ${date}report.html test.robot
```